# Run C code on Android without compiling the entire tree

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, adb

I have a C code which I want to add to the Android C libraries.

I can build and execute the coed when I am compiling the entire android tree.
I would like to be able to add the code to an existing compiled android environment.
i.e. To use a built device and just push my application and execute it there.

I succeeded to compile my code on windows platform for linux using the NDK and to push it using `adb push` command.

When trying to execute using the `adb execute`

I get the following error:

> **[Android] not executable: magic=7F45**

Comment: What do you mean by "add to the Android C libraries"? Are you talking about modifying one of the existing .so files on the phone to execute your code?

Comment: No. I want my code to be able to call an existing c library

Answer (score 0):

Magic 7F45 means the binary is a [linux ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) and is not compiled to the ARM arch (you can find out what arch using `file`).  You need to create the standalone toolchain using the NDK and then use it to build the correct binaries.

Here are the main details of how you do this courtesy of the [android dev site](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html):

> The NDK allows you to create a "customized" toolchain installation to make life easier. For example, consider the following command:

```
$NDK/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-5 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain
```

> This will create a directory named /tmp/my-android-toolchain containing a copy of the android-5/arch-arm sysroot, and of the toolchain binaries.
>
> Note that by default, the ARM-based toolchain will be selected by the script.
>     Use the '--arch=x86' option to specify the x86-based one,
>     use the '--arch=mips' option to specify the MIPS-based one, or alternatively '--toolchain='.
>
> You can later use it directly with something like:

```
export PATH=/tmp/my-android-toolchain/bin:$PATH 
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

The environment variables shown above allow you to make use of `configure` or `make` to build 3rd party code for the arch you specified.  You may of course just use the compiler directly.